# Adding Borders stripes to macro enabled word templates

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

Can anyone help me how to add blue coloured border stripes to macro enabled word templates using VBA Script. Please find attached image for reference.[

[image]

I have tried with various VBA scripts. They were not so perfect. Can anyone send me code it would help me.

Comment: Always helps to post the code you tried, along with a description of exactly what issues you had with that code.

Comment: Why do you need to use VBA to do that? Why can’t you add the borders to the template?